# Using echo with at command

Tags: linux, bash

Why doesn't this print a statement to the terminal:

```
      ~$ at 12:00
       > ./script.sh
       > echo "Task complete"
       > CTRL_D
```

I wrote it in the script as such also:

```
       #!/bin/sh
       touch new.txt
       echo "Task complete"
```

and that doesn't work either. I want to be clear that the file is created but the message is not executed.

Comment: Sure it's executed. It's just not sent to the TTY from which you created the job.

Comment: That's normal and expected, and the only reasonable behavior -- if it tried to connect to the TTY that started the job, what's it supposed to do if that TTY isn't open any more when the job runs, or is attached to a different window with someone else logged in?

Comment: "The user will be
     mailed standard error and standard output from his commands, if any."

Comment: Output is mailed to the user who created the job. If you have your system's mailer configured correctly, check your mail.

Comment: BTW, this is more a fit for [unix.se], being at its core a question about the behavior of OS-provided tools.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Comment: As a side note, instead of echoing the status then and there, it is better to append it to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the script. The result I got was a new file named "new.txt" was created and "Task Complete" was printed to the terminal normally.

The result I got after typing "at 12:00...etc" was the following message: `job 1 at Tue Oct  3 12:00:00 2017`. Basically, I think it just created job 1 that will be executed at 12:00. The message does execute, just not to terminal.